# Scopes in JSF 2

Tags: jsf-2

I have a CRUD application.. Where in the data is fetched, displayed n edited n stored back to db. Also there is a sequential access between pages & the information entered on the first page is needed on the second page & so forth. What would be the best scope & why ?

When to use which scope? What is the life-cycle of each scope.

Also, I couldn't find any good tutorial on scopes. If you are aware of the same, please guide.

Thanks,
Shikha

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to choose the right bean scope?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7031885/how-to-choose-the-right-bean-scope)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There is a detailed explanation of JSF scopes in BalusC's excellent tutorial [Communication in JSF 2.0](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2011/09/communication-in-jsf-20.html#ManagedBeanScopes).

As rule of thumb I would recommend to always choose the most narrow scope in order to reduce the state that is saved on the server side. Your application would have a bad scalability if you kept everything in session scope. The view scope is especially useful if you are working with ajax. For non-ajax views the request scope is often sufficient.

Comment: +Flash Scope: http://andyschwartz.wordpress.com/2009/07/31/whats-new-in-jsf-2/#scopes

Comment: @edze: Flash scope is broken in Mojarra. Don't use it.

Comment: Thank you. I didn't use it before. Good to know it.